# Mongoose: `findOne()` returns undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to find a single document from my mongoDB database but it's always returning `undefined`, but the that document exists in the collection

```js
User.findOne({ discordId: (message.author.id) }, (err, data) => {
    console.log(data) // returns `undefined`
})
```

The `User` model

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    discordId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Decimal128,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    playing: {
        type: Boolean
    },
    response: {
        type: String
    },
    points: {
        type: Number
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema, 'User')
```

Comment: Are you connected to the right database?

Comment: @AllanChua, Yep I'm connected to the right database

Comment: `findOne` method returns `undefined` when there is no matching document in the collection. Are you sure that your query filter specifies a matching document?

Comment: @prasad_, Yep there is a matching document in the collection. Check this [image](https://imgur.com/CWHGdfa.png) for the document and this [image](https://imgur.com/Y6JOSO0.png) for the code

Comment: _"...your query filter specifies a matching document"_ - I mean does the query filter specifies the matching field value.

Comment: @prasad_ Yeah there is

Comment: The schema definition says the data type is `mongoose.Schema.Types.Decimal128`  - your query filter should match that data type. MongoDB has four different number types - int, long, double and decimal. By default it is either int (for small numbers) or double (for large numbers). For example, you will not be able to match an int type number with decimal type number.

Comment: @prasad_, Yep, The `message.author.id` is `851756211841925141` which turns out to be in the collection

Comment: You can check the type of  number value in the document using the [$type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/type/) operator.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241648/discussion-between-kira-and-prasad).